# How to apply filters while running BDD scenarios using QAF BDD2 framework?

Tags: bdd, qaf

We have feature file with scenarios that are applicable to only mobile and desktop. I want to run only mobile scenarios in my regression. How should I add this filter so that it picks only mobile scenarios using QAF BDD2?

```
Ex: Feature Hello
@channel['desktop','mobile']
Scenario: This is applicable for desktop and mobile
Given ..
When ..
Then ..

@channel['desktop']
Scenario: This is applicable for desktop only
Given ..
When ..
Then ..

@channel['mobile']
Scenario: This is applicable for mobile only
Given ..
When ..
Then ..
```

When I try to run this it runs and skips desktop scenarios. How shoud I add filter just to run Mobile scenario and avoid skipping desktop scenarios? I tried below code adding in config xml did not work

```
<parameter name="include" value="{'channel': ['mobile']}" />
```

and added

```
<method-selectors>
    <method-selector>
        <selector-class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.testng.pro.QAFMethodSelector" />
    </method-selector>
</method-selectors>
```

in xml also. Filter is not working. Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `:` to separate Meta key value pair. For example:

@channel:['desktop','mobile']